# Not able to select many to many in Django admin as right selection pane not visible

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have a model which contains ManyToMany relationship. But when I go to admin and want to add object from admin, the right pane where selection goes is not visible.

[image: django admin]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to select many to many fields and see them in a right pane, you should add 
[`filter_horizontal`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal) to your admin class:

> `admin.py`

```
class TheModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ['the_name_of_the_field']


admin.site.register(TheModel, TheModelAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How did I forget that!!